# How do I selectively ignore clang's warnings about use of deprecated objective-c implementations?

Tags: objective-c, clang, pragma, suppress-warnings

I'm updating [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/) for iOS 5.1, and I want to be warned about usage of deprecated Objective-C methods.  Unfortunately, `MGSplitViewController` supports iOS 3.2, so I want to support all deprecated callbacks, but ignore warnings about them.

I've enabled warnings about "Overriding Deprecated Objective-C Methods" (`CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS`) in my target build settings, but I can't ignore it with

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS"

- (void) deprecated_objc_method_override {
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS` corresponds to `-Wdeprecated-implementations`, which Xcode doesn't show in its "Quick Help" area.  So the following works:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-implementations"

- (void) deprecated_objc_method_override {
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Another option, if modifying the actually source might not be wanted, is to turn off the warning when compiling specific files (like those that implement the MGSplit classes. For example, passing compiler flags just to those implementation files like `-Wno-deprecated-implementations`

Answer (score 15):

There's also the related `deprecated-declarations` flag. This suppresses warnings like "'foo' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.10 - Use -bar instead".

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

   :

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```